# Weird sequelize error while trying to run my app from my server

Tags: mysql, node.js, linux, ubuntu, sequelize.js

[image]

This happens when I run node app.js from my server through putty.

I have MySql installed and running, and my code works fine from my local machine with no problems but I can't seem to get it to run on my server. Any ideas that may be causing this?

Comment: still haven't figured it out.. ive tried reinstalling different mysql's but it's always the same thing

Comment: Can you paste the full SQL command you're trying to run? The error is telling you that it contains a syntax error.

Comment: There is a `sync([options={}])` method of the `Sequelize` object that you must be calling in your code which might be causing this error while running the corresponding sql queries. By default, the sync method [logs all SQL to console](http://docs.sequelizejs.com/en/latest/api/sequelize/?highlight=sync#syncoptions-promise). So check this option and the console and see what's that query its trying to fire when `sync` is called.

Answer (score 0):

```
 createdAt:{
        type: db.Sequelize.DATE(3),
        unique: false,
        allowNull: false
    }
```

so basically what was throwing the error was the DATE(3).

I had MySQL 5.5 installed and dates to the millisecond aren't supported until 5.7